# Disadvantages of CouchDB

Tags: nosql, couchdb, database

I've very recently fallen in love with *CouchDB*. I'm pretty excited by its enormous benefits and by its beauty. Now I want to make sure that I haven't missed any show-stopping disadvantages.

What comes to your mind? Attached is a list of points that I have collected. Is there anything to add?

- Blog posts from as late as 2010 claim "not mature enough" (whatever that's worth).
- Slower than in-memory DBMS.
- In-place updates require server-side logic [(update handlers)](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers).
- Trades disk vs. speed: Databases can become huge compared to other DBMS (compaction functionality exists, though).
- "Only" *eventual* consistency.
- Temporary views on large datasets are *very* slow.
- Replication of large databases [may fail](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-690).
- Map/reduce paradigm requires rethinking (only for completeness).

The only point that worries *me* is #3 (in-place updates), because it's quite inconvenient.

Comment: What about HTTP communication overhead? What about the difficulty to constrain values in couch (uniques are hard to do)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- **The data is in JSON**

Which means that documents are quite large (BigData, network bandwidth, speed), and having descriptive key names actually hurts, since they add up to the document size.

- **No built in full text search**

  Although there are ways: [couchdb-lucene](https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene), [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/)

*plus [some more](http://wiki.fluidproject.org/display/fluid/Schema-less+Databases):*

- **It doesn't support transactions**

It means that enforcing uniqueness of one field across all documents is not safe, for example, enforcing that a username is unique. Another consequence of CouchDB's inability to support the typical notion of a transaction is that things like inc/decrementing a value and saving it back are also dangerous. There aren't many instances that we would want to simply inc/decrement some value where we couldn't just store the individual documents separately and aggregate them with a view.

- **Relational data**

If the data makes a lot of sense to be in 3rd normal form, and we try to follow that form in CouchDB,  we are going to run into a lot of trouble. A possible way to solve this problem is with view collations, but we might constantly going to be fighting with the system. If  the data can be reformatted to be much more denormalized, then CouchDB will work fine.

- **Data warehouse**

The problem with this is that temporary views in CouchDB on large datasets are really slow. Using CouchDB and permanent views could work quite well. However, in most of cases, a Column-Oriented Database of some sort is a much better tool for the data warehousing job.

**But CouchDB Rocks!**

But don't let it discorage you: NoSQL DBs that are written in Erlang (CouchDB, Riak) are the best, since Erlang is meant for distributed systems. Have fun with Couch!

Answer (score 5):

2 more things, which make me cry when using CouchDB (though it's awesome):

- It is not designed for frequently updated data
- It doesn't have built-in fulltext search

Comment: What do you mean by "not designed for frequently updated data"?

Comment: When data is updated in CouchDB all views become stale and next time you request data by index it gets rebuilt. This may tale huge amount of time (more than 10 seconds in our case at the time I wrote this comment 8 years ago). I believe CouchDB2 can behave in a different way.

Answer (score 3):

- Lack of reader ACLs (does exist for writers, however)

As an old Lotus Domino pro I was looking to CouchDB as an alternative for a new project I'm kicking off and found the limits on readers to be very weak in Couch vs. Domino. In my app security is an important consideration and Couch would require a middleware layer to handle reader security.

If you have database in which it's okay that all defined users can see all the documents, then Couch looks like an interesting platform.

If restricting reads is needed then you'll need to look to a middleware solution or consider another alternative.

Note to CouchDB developers: Improve the platform security options. I realize they will diminish performance when used but note that and make the option available.

Now back to determining which database to use...

Comment: Yes. This stops me from running Couch-only applications.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, Domino 8.5.3 includes JSONRest support via Domino Data Service features.

You get the full Domino security model along with REST support. Very nice.

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpViewCategories.xsp?lookupName=Domino%20Data%20Service

Answer (score 1):

- currently no support for ad-hoc queries (might change with advent of UnQL)
- lack of binary protocol support for faster communication

Comment: UnQL is pointless to be honest. If all NoSQL databases were to support UnQL we'd soon see NoUnQL databases. NoSQL databases are interesting in a way that they aren't designed on top of a query language but on a way to store data. This makes things as crazy as Rest database like CouchDB possible.
As for the binary protocol, it could be useful but as far as I can tell, speed of the http protocole isn't exactly the big problem with couchdb.

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing to do with CouchDB itself, but being a relative newcomer on the scene means that most sysadmins are still unfamiliar with it and won't allow it anywhere near "their" data centers. If you're in a situation where you're deploying to an environment you don't control yourself, this can be quite the battle.

Answer (score 0):

1. Lack of support for data archiving - No official support for data
   archiving is provided with couch db open source distribution.
2. Deleting records from db is not straightforward
3. No option to set a expire (TTL) flag for documents